# Java to count sequence of String

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap, set

I'm looking to find a way to group and count a sequence of words in a String.

Example

```
String  = " 15, 15 , 15 , 2 , 2 , 0 "
```

The output that I'm looking for is

```
15(3)
2(2)
0(1)
```

In other word , it must be unsorted , so i will know the sequence will be like 3x15 then 2x2 and 0x1

So it will have a pattern like `15(3)2(2)0(1)`

I try this code

```
String str = "15|15|15|11|15|15|15|15|15|12|";
        String[] splitStr = str.split("\\|");

        Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<>();
        for (String word : splitStr) {
            if (wordCount.containsKey(word)) {
                // Map already contains the word key. Just increment it's count by 1
                wordCount.put(word, wordCount.get(word) + 1);
            } else {
                // Map doesn't have mapping for word. Add one with count = 1
                wordCount.put(word, 1);
            }
        }


        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : wordCount.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.toString().replaceAll("=","(")+")");
        }
```

But the output become

15(8)
11(1)
12(1)

I'm looking for output like

15(3)
11(1)
15(5)
12(1)

Comment: What did you try, where are you stuck

Comment: If the string is like this = 15,15,15,11,15,15,15,15,15,12, i want the output will become 15(3)11(1)15(5)12(1) , even the no 15 appear 2 times.

Comment: Then that should be in the question as well, along with what are you expecting and how you're stuck on it. Also don't mix the delimiters, stick to one notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a homework, isn't it?

How to split a string? `StringTokenizer` along delimiters: space and comma; or `String.split`, but that uses a RegEx.
How to group and count? `HashMap` with the numbers as keys, and their count as values.
How to keep the order the keys were inserted: `LinkedHashMap`

#### Re: update

It looks like you got the above already. Your new requirement

> "If a number appears more than once it should be counted separately"

this makes it a little more complicated, you can't do that with the Java built-in classes.

A little guide: you essentially need to find the sequences and count how many identical numbers are there. You'll know where the sequence boundaries are by the previous and current (or current and next, depending on your style of thinking) being different. If they're the same then you're mid-sequence so just count. If they're different you need to make note of the new number.

Implement the following thinking in code:

```
15|15|15|11|15|15|15|15|15|12|
^ 15, that's new, we have 1
15|15|15|11|15|15|15|15|15|12|
   ^ 15 again, we have 2
15|15|15|11|15|15|15|15|15|12|
      ^ 15 again, we have 3
15|15|15|11|15|15|15|15|15|12|
         ^ 11, that's new. So 15(3). 11, we have 1
15|15|15|11|15|15|15|15|15|12|
            ^ 15, that's new. So 11(1). 15, we have 1
15|15|15|11|15|15|15|15|15|12|
               ^ 15 again, we have 2
15|15|15|11|15|15|15|15|15|12|
                  ^ 15 again, we have 3
15|15|15|11|15|15|15|15|15|12|
                     ^ 15 again, we have 4
15|15|15|11|15|15|15|15|15|12|
                        ^ 15 again, we have 5
15|15|15|11|15|15|15|15|15|12|
                           ^ 12, that's new. So 15(5). 12, we have 1
15|15|15|11|15|15|15|15|15|12|
                              ^ finished so let's not forget the last one 12(1)
```

Comment: i have edited question with the sample code i used. tq

Comment: and I've replied just a second ago :)